# Mixed content in JAXB generated files

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, hl7-v3

Consider the following type definition in my XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="ED" mixed="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
     <xs:extension base="BIN">
        <!-- I cut some data here -->
     </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I found that JAXB has a hard time generating code for `mixed` elements.
I tried using `<jaxb:globalBindings generateMixedExtensions="true"/>`, but that isn't supported very well and generates awkward `List<Serializable>` code.

So I thought I could modify some element through my custom binding:

```
<bindings
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../../processable/coreschemas/datatypes-base.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@mixed='true']" multiple="true">
            <property>
                <javaType><!-- What do I do here? --></javaType>
            </property> 
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Basically, I want all elements which specify `mixed=true` to have a custom `value` or `content` field (`String`) which holds the CDATA between the tags. For instance for my `ED` type it could be like this in XML, the title element uses `ED` as its type:

`<title>Hello, I'm a title!</title>` should yield `Hello, I'm a title!` as its content.

How do I do this?

For those of you interested: I'm trying to generate code for the HL7v3 CDA specifications.